# No default authentication/challenge schemes found, but they're set in Startup

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

In an effort to port a .NET Framework web API to .NET Core 2.2, I ran into some issues when configuring authentication using AD. The old app would have something like this:

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
    new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Tenant = "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { ValidAudience = "1111..."}
    });
```

The way we use the API is as follows: a web app handles authentication (gets a JWT) and uses said token with our API for certain actions. Searching around the web I found [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/TodoListService) sample which uses `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI`. I now ended up with the following:

`appsettings.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "AzureAd": {
        "Domain": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
        "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
        "TenantId": "2222...",
        "ClientId": "1111..."
    }
}
```

`Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme;
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

The problem is that when I use the generated token (that works with the .NET Framework app) I get the following error: `InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me you haven't added the Azure AD authentication scheme. That usually looks something like `services.AddAuthentication().AddAzureADBearer()`.